# How many rising pipes for LOX at the the Saturn V launch tower?

Tags: apollo-program, launch-site, saturn-v, lox

The Saturn V used liquid oxygen for all three stages plus the Apollo Service Module. Were all these LOX tanks filled using the same rising pipe or did they use a seperate pipe for each tank?

[image]

Using the same vertical pipe was not easy due to different tank volumes, filling flow rates and pressure differences caused by the height above the ground.

The same problem with liquid hydrogen used for the second and third stage as well as the service module.